# How to change the class of a specific window in AHK V1.1+?

Tags: autohotkey

- I have a specific window ("x") that I want to execute on It only some commands(As shown below), and this window("x") has the same class as some other windows. The problem is when I run another window ("y") from another program, and this window("y") has the same class as the window("x") that I want commands to be executed on. This window("y") also applies to the commands, but I don't want the commands to apply to the window("y") I just want the commands to apply to the window ("x")
- I've tried to apply commands to the window("x") using its title or (exe) or its (ID) or its (PID) instead of the class, but it didn't work(Commands apply only if I use the class)

I've tried this, but it didn't  work :
; ....................................................................
1 example:

```
    If not WinExist("QTranslate")  ; "QTranslate" this is the title of 
    the window "y" that has the same class of "x"
    {
    Loop {
    WinWaitActive, ahk_class #32770  ; this is the class of the 
    window("x")
    WinSet,AlwaysOnTop,On, ahk_class #32770
    WinWaitClose, ahk_class #32770
    }
    }
    Return
```

; ....................................................................
Example 2:

```
    #If not WinActive("QTranslate") and WinExist("ahk_class #32770") ; close error win
    RButton::
    AppsKey::
    Loop, 3{
    Winclose,ahk_class #32770 ; this is the class of the window("x")
    }
    #If
```

- When I open the window ("y") and press a RButton or AppsKey, that commands applies to that window
  ; ....................................................................
- Is there a way to change the class of a window using AHK or another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the WinTitle parameter you can specify more than one criterion
for narrowing down the search  of a specific window. See [**Multiple Criteria**](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#multi).

e.g.

```
If !WinExist("QTranslate ahk_exe QTranslate.exe") ; "!" means "NOT"
```

or

```
If !WinExist("QTranslate ahk_exe QTranslate.exe", "WinText")
```

or

```
If !WinExist("QTranslate ahk_exe QTranslate.exe", "WinText", "ExcludeTitlePart")
```

Use the **Window Spy** tool that comes with AHK to get the correct information you need.